# NPE caused by Google Firebase SDK

Tags: android, firebase, nullpointerexception, firebase-cloud-messaging

Just integrated Google **firebase** Cloud Messaging and Remote Config SDK  version **9.4** in the new version of my app, some **firebase** related crash happened. similar question found [java.lang.NullPointerException at GoogleApiActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418397/java-lang-nullpointerexception-at-googleapiactivity)

```
1 java.lang.RuntimeException:Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.intube.player.downloader/com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
2 android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3553)
3 ......
4 Caused by:
5 java.lang.NullPointerException:
6 com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity.a(Unknown Source)
7 com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity.onActivityResult(Unkn>own Source)
8 android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5456)
9 android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3549)
10 android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3596)
11 android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151)
12 android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1369)
13 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
14 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
15 android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
16 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
17 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
18 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
19 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:645)
20 dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Where exactly are you getting this error? when a notification arrives? when you build your project? in any particular class of the Firebase services?

Comment: @shaobin0604 Include some code snippets . that could be much helpful

Comment: @GeorgeLBA the crash is reported by [Fabric](https://get.fabric.io/),  **4.5%** DAU are affected. But I cannot reproduce this issue on my test device(Nexus 4). Have not sent any firebase cloud message yet.